# Powershell - Use multidimention arrays for storing data - Need suggestion

Tags: powershell

I'm googling since a while, but I didn't find a solution to my problem.
I have to say I'm newbie in Powershell.

I would like to create the following array
$a = (A,B,C,D) where
A = 1 string (always)
B = 1 string (always)
C = undefined number of strings. I need to be able to add elements dynamically
D = undefined number of strings. I need to be able to add elements dynamically (same number as C)

Is this possible?
Example of 2 elements of the array

1. ("WSTM0123456", "192.168.10.155",("WSTM8765421","WSTM9856454","WSTM1289765"),("192.36.36.36", "187.25.25.25","192.69.89.65"))
2. ("WLDN1251254", "156.25.36.54", ("WLDN1234512", "WLDN9865323"), ("187.154.12.12","163.136.25.98"))

I don't know a priori how many elements will be in C and D and I'll have to append strings in position C and D with a for cycle.

Scope: group many strings (C & D) under the same string (A/B) which are in common.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but it's probably quite painful as dealing with arrays is sometimes cumbersome in PowerShell due to lots of implicit flattening.

I'd suggest creating a custom type for this. Then you can also give the individual parts useful names (I don't know the purpose of what you're doing here, so I'm making up names here. Feel free to change):

```
$properties = @{
  Name = 'WSTM0123456';
  IP = [ipaddress]'192.168.10.155';
  ListOfNames = @("WSTM8765421","WSTM9856454","WSTM1289765");
  ListOfIPs = [ipaddress[]]@("192.36.36.36", "187.25.25.25","192.69.89.65")
}

$foo = New-Object PSObject -Property @properties
```

Then you can simply append new items like so:

```
$foo.ListOfNames += 'AnotherName'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty much the same idea.  Use a hash table, and make two of the elements arrays.  This is how you would create the arrays "on the fly" at runtime, without knowing what any of the contents were going to be in advance, taking $x and putting any item that starts with "t" in "C" , and everything else in "D":

```
 $a = @{A = "Some string";B = "Some other string"}

 $x = "one","two","three","four","five"

 $x |% {
     if ($_ -match "^t"){$a["C"] += @($_)}
     else {$a["D"] += @($_)}
     }

 $a.a
 Some string

 $a.b
 Some other string

 $a.c
 two
 three


 $a.d
 one
 four
 five


$obj = new-object psobject -property $a
```